# How to return keywords and values into json object using MySQL and python

Tags: mysql, json, python-3.x

I have a code that fetches data from a MySQL database, it return values but not the keywords. I need keywords so I can make calls later in JavaScript.
Instead of keywords which are firstname lastname username and mail it returns as 0 1 2 3.

0: "Luka"
1: "Tubic"
2: "Tubex"
3: "test@mail.com"

It should return

"firstname": "Luka"
"lastname":"Tubic"
"username":"Tubex"
"mail":"test@mail.com"

this is python script

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify, request, redirect, url_for
import mysql.connector
import random
import string
import smtplib

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='www')

def _connect():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='root',
                                         auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',
                                         database='User')
    connection.commit()
    return connection


@app.route('/admin/users', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTION'])
def dummyadmin():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        connection = _connect()
        c = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
        query = 'SELECT first_name,last_name,username,email from user.user'
        c.execute(query)
        users = c.fetchall()

        if users is None:
            return None

        connection.commit()
        c.close()
        print(users)
        return jsonify(users)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        connection = _connect()
        c = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
        


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The solution is documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorbuffereddict.html): use a DictCursor.

```
c = connection.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True)
```

NB : by default a db-api cursor yields [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) which are indeed indexed by position, not by column name. This is a pretty standard and natural  representation of relational data, and is less costly than [dicts](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a function called "json_object" which takes the list of input and return as JSON object as below, so, in your case instead of fetching rows in the different column, you can consider getting as json_object from Db itself.

```
    SELECT json_object('first_name',first_name,'last_name',last_name,'username',username,'email',email) as jsonString from user.user;
```

Output format

```
{"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Edial", "username":"john.edial","email": "john@wddil.com"}
```